# trying to update a column with difference between 2 dates when one can be NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

With the following code:

```
Update FactQuote
  SET ConversionDays = 
  CASE
    WHEN 
      ConversionDate = NULL THEN NULL
    Else
      DATEDIFF(day, InitialContactDate, ConversionDate)
  END
```

Keep getting this message:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What kind of db are you using?

Comment: I tried the following variations

Comment: Update FactQuote
  SET ConversionDays = DATEDIFF(day, InitialContactDate, ConversionDate)
  where ConversionDate != NULL 

Update FactQuote
  SET ConversionDays = 
  CASE
    WHEN 
      ConversionDate = NULL THEN NULL
 Else
   DATEDIFF(day, InitialContactDate, ConversionDate)
  END

Comment: What is the data type of `ConversionDays`?  Edit your question and show the table definition (at least for the relevant columns).

Comment: Also, when comparing values with null, you can't use the `=` or `!=` operators. You have to do `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a simplification (which is too long for a comment).

`DATEDIFF()` -- like many other functions -- returns `NULL` when either date argument is `NULL`.  So, you can simplify your expression to:

```
Update FactQuote
  SET ConversionDays = DATEDIFF(day, InitialContactDate, ConversionDate);
```